How can I remove upgradability in case of UUPS proxy?
I have my contract which inteherits UUPS upgradability. Now due to some issues, I want to completely remove UUPS proxy and implement transparent proxy.
Any way I can do this?

Since UUPS relies on the implementation contract to have the upgradeability logic, switching this way may be possible. Once the switch is done, the implementation contract just has useless upgradeability code.
Basically you should:

Deploy a new transparent proxy and make that point to the implementation contract
Migrate state to the new proxy, somehow
Migrate proxy access logic to the new proxy
Migrate all off-chain references to use the new proxy

I don't know if this is possible to accomplish for you. But it may be doable.

But I am unable to do anything as the proxy is showing function upgradeToAndCall. I am able to do that on testnet by producing same scenario but not on mainnet.

Then you have different code on the different networks.
But in any case you don't want to upgrade the logic contract. You want to switch the proxy - and that's not something that's supported directly by the proxy or logic contract itself.
